# Create an object from another objects type

Tags: vb.net, types, createobject

In Visual Basic.net, can I create an Object, or a List of T with the type from another object.

Here is some code:

```
Dim TestObjectType As Author
Dim TestObject As TestObjectType.GetType
```

I am getting an error:

> TestObjectType.GetType is not defined

**EDIT**

Can I create a Type object of a certain type, and then create objects, lists or cast objects to this type from this Type object?

Comment: I doubt this would compile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Dim TestObject As TestObjectType.GetType` will look for a type named `GetType` in the namespace `TestObjectType`.

---

To create an instance of a class using `System.Type`, you can use [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/wccyzw83.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb):

```
Dim TestObject = Activator.CreateInstance(TestObjectType.GetType())
```

To create a generic list, you can use [`Type.MakeGenericType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx):

```
Dim listType = GetType(List(Of )).MakeGenericType(TestObjectType.GetType())
Dim list = Activator.CreateInstance(listType)
```

Note that both snippets above return an `Object`; however, you can make use of generics to achieve compile time safety:

```
Dim TestObject = CreateNew(TestObjectType)
Dim AuthorList = CreateNewList(TestObjectType)

...

Function CreateNew(Of T As New)(obj As T) As T 
    Return New T()
End Function

Function CreateNewList(Of T)(obj As T) As List(Of T)
    Return New List(Of T)
End Function
```

Comment: *Can I create a Type object of a certain type?* You mean something like `Dim authorType As System.Type = GetType(Author)`? *and then create objects, lists* Yes, look at my answer. * or cast objects to this type from this Type object* That doesn't make sense, since casting is only useful at compile-time. You don't know which type the `System.Type` you like to cast to will actually represent.